# Node MCU problema de compilación en Mac

Tags: arduino

Hace unas semanas compre la placa NodeMCU, la quiero programar con el Arduino IDE pero cuando la conecto me aparece este error :

> ```
> Arduino:1.8.8 (Mac OS X), Tarjeta:"NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, 
> Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, 
> Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200" fork/exec 
> /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8- 
> arduino11/ctags: bad CPU type in executable Error compilando para la tarjeta 
> NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module). Este informe podría contener más información con
> ```

```
"Mostrar salida detallada durante la compilación" opción habilitada en Archivo 
-> Preferencias
```

Ya instale los drivers del CH340G y el CP2102 e incluso ya tengo registrada la tarjeta en el board manager pero me sigue apareciendo el error de compilación.

Gracias